Flutter Shaders syntax error, unexpected VEC3, expecting COMMA or SEMICOLON
I am working with Flutter shaders and I am getting the following error:

syntax error, unexpected VEC3, expecting COMMA or SEMICOLON

Here is my shader:
#include <flutter/runtime_effect.glsl>

// Uniform variables passed from the application
uniform vec2 uResolution; // The resolution of the screen (width, height)
uniform float uTime;      // The elapsed time in seconds
uniform vec2 uMouse;      // The mouse position (x, y)

// Output color of the fragment
out vec4 fragColor;

// Function to plot a line on the Y-axis using a value between 0.0 and 1.0
float plot(vec2 normalizedCoords, float lineYPosition) {    
    // Create a smooth transition around the lineYPosition
    return smoothstep(lineYPosition - 0.02, lineYPosition, normalizedCoords.y) 
         - smoothstep(lineYPosition, lineYPosition + 0.02, normalizedCoords.y);
}

void main() {

    vec3 white = vec3(1.0); // White
    vec3 black = vec3(0.0); // Black
    vec3 red = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); // Red
    vec3 green = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // Green
    vec3 blue = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // Blue

    // Get the rgba values of the color
    vec3 color = blue;

    // Multiply each color component by an alpha value
    float alpha = 0.5;
    vec3 colorWithAlpha = color * alpha;

    float y = FlutterFragCoord().y / uResolution.y;
    vec3 background = vec3(y);

    // Normalized coordinates
    vec2 st = FlutterFragCoord() / uResolution;

    float y = pow(st.x, 5)

    // Create a line at the center of the screen
    vec3 line = mix(background, colorWithAlpha, plot(FlutterFragCoord() / uResolution, y));

    // Output the final color with premultiplied alpha
    fragColor = vec4(line, alpha);
}


As the error message suggests, each line in a GLSL or .frag file needs to end with a semi-colon. I fixed it by adding a semi-colon at the end of this line:
float y = pow(st.x, 5);

I am using the Shader language support for VS Code extension so I thought it would lint this for me but it didn't.
